# StardDate & EndDate from a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-01-19 07:49:09.907 |
| 3 | 2021-01-19 07:49:11.427 |
| 3 | 2021-01-19 07:49:12.443 |
| 3 | 2021-01-19 07:49:13.487 |
| 9 | 2021-01-19 07:49:10.753 |
| 9 | 2021-01-19 07:49:16.203 |
| 9 | 2021-01-19 07:49:17.120 |
| 9 | 2021-01-19 07:49:18.033 |

What I need is creating a StartDate and Enddate from timestamp column for each id when the difference between timestamps is more than 2 seconds.

I'm using SQL Server for this.

What I did until now is

```
SELECT
  [id],
  [timestamp],
  lead([Timestamp]) over (order by [Timestamp])
from mytable
where id=9
```

The code worked when using the filter but is not working anymore when I'm doing it for all IDs.

Also the table has now more than 3 milions rows.

The expected output should be:

| id | startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2021-01-19 07:49:09.907 | 2021-01-19 07:49:11.427 |
| 3 | 021-01-19 07:49:11.427 | 2021-01-19 07:49:13.487 |
| 9 | 2021-01-19 07:49:10.753 | 2021-01-19 07:49:16.203 |
| 9 | 2021-01-19 07:49:16.203 | 2021-01-19 07:49:18.033 |

Comment: please tag your DBMS.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS and example of input and expected output.

Comment: "tag your DBMS" doesn't mean to add the `database` tag (which is implied with the `sql` tag), but the actual database _product_ you are using.  [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You say "when the difference is more than two seconds" but 07:49:11.427 is not more than 2 seconds since 07:49:09.907, so why is that row with 11.4 not dropped ? The only one of your desired output rows with a difference of more than 2 seconds is the third one

Comment: @CaiusJard I looked at seconds only. It doesn't matter really the difference between timestamps. can be 2 second or 12, the code should be the same.

Comment: @FlorinTiron . . . `2021-01-19 07:49:11.427` and `2021-01-19 07:49:11.427` are not two seconds apart.  Period.  They are the same.  Based on your description, there should be only one row for `3` for this data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bit of integer logic for the grouping would do this:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT id,
           [timestamp], --timestamp is a synonym for rowversion, which is NOT a time value; this is a confusing column name
           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [timestamp]) - 1) / 2 AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT id,
       MIN([timestamp]) AS StartTime,
       MAX([timestamp]) AS EndTime
FROM Grps
GROUP BY id,
         Grp
ORDER BY id,
         Grp;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bacf48a7cea14ed947b126cb8e959476)

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is creating a StartDate and Enddate from timestamp column for each id when the difference between timestamps is more than 2 seconds

For `id` 3, there are no examples where the timestamps are 2 seconds apart.  So, for your sample data and problem description, there should be only one row for `3`.

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  My suggestion is to get the previous timestamp and identify when an island starts by checking the 2 second limit.  Then, a cumulative sum of the island starts assigns a group:

```
select id, min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_timestamp >= dateadd(second, -2, timestamp) then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by id order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66f32191004828af41987d8196fad898) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can you tell me why in your example I have the first line for Id 9 has the same values for start and end? the first line for id 9 should be: 2021-01-19 07:49:10.753 and 2021-01-19 07:49:16.203. Walk me through this please.

Comment: Also you example is looking for the next record that is more than 2 seconds apart. In the database I have a timestamp every one second and sometimes there are more than one second. What I need is only those cases when this is happening . Thanks.

Comment: @FlorinTiron . . . I have quoted the question that this answers.  Your comment is not what the question is describing.